# Find $G'(0)$ where $G(x)=\int_0^{x+\pi} \frac{\sin(x+t)}{1+(x+t)^2} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I want to find $G'(0)$ where $$G(x)=\int_0^{x+\pi} \frac{\sin(x+t)}{1+(x+t)^2} dt,\hspace{2cm} x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

I notice that this decomposes nicely into being $G(x)=\int_0^{x+\pi} f(x+t) dt$ if $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}$, but am not sure if that is meaningless. I don't know how to find $G'$. Please help.

Comment: Using leibniz's law?

Comment: @razivo Is this Leibniz's rule? If so, I have to learn about this.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Put
$$u=t+x$$
it becomes

$$G(x)=\int_x^{2x+\pi}\frac{\sin(u)du}{1+u^2}$$
$$=\int_{-\pi}^{\color{red}{2}x}\frac{\sin(v+\pi)dv}{1+(v+\pi)^2}-\int_0^x\frac{\sin(u)du}{1+u^2}$$

thus
$$G'(x)=\color{red}{2}\frac{\sin(2x+\pi)}{1+(2x+\pi)^2}-\frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, but then how can I find $\int\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2} dx$?

Comment: @mathim1881 You do not need that for $ G'(0)$

Comment: So i derivate wrt $x$ on each side? I do not remember/know how to do that since the integrals are over another variable. Could you please help me further?

Comment: @mathim1881 i just added some line showing how to compute G'(x).

Comment: Wow, thanks so much this makes sense now. Just to be clear, the parts from the $-\pi$ and $0$ boundaries cancel each other yes?

Comment: The derivative of $ \int_a^{h(x)} f(t)dt $ is $ h'(x)f(h(x))$.

Comment: Sorry, i have to eat now. next time.